# Is it ethical for an instructor to use their own textbook in an undergraduate course?

Tags: books, conflict-of-interest

Students in an undergraduate course often have no choice of a textbook for the subject and are expected to buy the book recommended by the instructor. The expectations can be advisory or mandatory. Given the degree of control that an instructor has over their undergraduate students, especially freshmen and sophomores, is it ethical to use a textbook authored by the instructor in an undergraduate course? Does such requirement not constitute a conflict of interest?

P.S. I understand that practically this is done times and again, but I would like to sense the general feelings.

Comment: That is usually why the instructor makes the effort to write a textbook...

Comment: It is very common. However, some perfectly ethical (but poor) profs will give you free electronic version of his book.